# Get number from a string

Tags: java

I have this part of a html code:

```
&quot;urn:li:fsd_jobPosting:3374616185&
```

In my case I have this String expression which is found many times into html table rows but with different number.

For example is it possible to get the number based on a expression for example `&quot;urn:li:fsd_jobPosting:<>&`?

Comment: Why is extracting the string between last `:` and `&` and then using a suitable string-to-int function not an answer? What did you try? What problems occurred? With "expression", do you mean "regular expression"?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=\&quot;urn:li:fsd_jobPosting:)(.*?)(?=\&)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3A0iW/1)